Avoid Putting Data in a Group By SQL
I am working on converting values to overpunch by joining an overpunch table to a purchases table, but for a report that sums up the purchases I am having trouble avoiding putting overpunch in the group by. Below is my current code and the overpunch table I am using. I think this could be solved with a CTE but I have not had luck with it yet.
SELECT 
 ,ID
 ,LEFT(RIGHT('000000000000' + SUM(CustomerPaid),12),11) + o1.overpunch
 ,LEFT(RIGHT('000000000000' + SUM(CustomerSaved),12),11) + o2.overpunch
FROM Table

LEFT JOIN OverPunch_Values o1
  ON RIGHT(CustomerPaid, 1) = o1.numeric AND SIGN(CustomerPaid) = o1.VarCharSign

LEFT JOIN OverPunch_Values o2
  ON RIGHT(CustomerSaved, 1) = o2.numeric AND SIGN(CustomerSaved) = o2.VarCharSign

GROUP BY ID, o1.overpunch, o2.overpunch




Overpunch
Numeric
Sign
VarCharSign




}
0
-1
-1


J
1
-1
-1


K
2
-1
-1


L
3
-1
-1


M
4
-1
-1


N
5
-1
-1


O
6
-1
-1


P
7
-1
-1


Q
8
-1
-1


R
9
-1
-1


{
0
0
1


A
1
1
1


B
2
1
1


C
3
1
1


D
4
1
1


E
5
1
1


F
6
1
1


G
7
1
1


H
8
1
1


I
9
1
1


{
0
0
0




it would massivly helo if we has data for table and wanted result

the wanted result is necessary, becuase https://dbfiddle.uk/5FLeTA6W is a possible solution  but nit the only one

Suggest title change: "Convert sum to overstrike / zoned decimal representation" or similar.

(Wow, it has been a long time since I've seen IBM/EBCDIC zoned decimal number representation (aka overpunch), and that was to convert-from legacy data, instead of convert-to. It's surprising sometimes how long legacy data formats stay around.)
I see a couple of problems with your current query.

It appears that you wish get the sums of your CustomerPaid and CustomerSaved values, but are joining to your overpunch table using the individual (not summed) values. You will need to group and sum the values in a subselect or CTE before performing the join.
Your attempt at zero-padding your values is not working, because the addition operator will convert a string to a number instead of a number to a string when "adding" mixed values. This can be resolved by explicitly converting the number to a string or using the CONCAT() function that will conveniently do the same.
To properly handle negative numbers, you need to use ABS() to eliminate a possible sign character when formatting your number.

The corrected query would be something like:
WITH SumData AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        SUM(CustomerPaid) AS SumCustomerPaid,
        SUM(CustomerSaved) AS SumCustomerSaved
    FROM Data
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT 
    ID
    , SumCustomerPaid
    , SumCustomerSaved
    , LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000000', ABS(SumCustomerPaid)), 12), 11) + o1.overpunch AS EncodedCustomerPaid
    , LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000000000', ABS(SumCustomerSaved)), 12), 11) + o2.overpunch AS EncodedCustomerSaved
FROM SumData

LEFT JOIN OverPunch_Values o1
  ON RIGHT(SumCustomerPaid, 1) = o1.numeric AND SIGN(SumCustomerPaid) = o1.VarCharSign

LEFT JOIN OverPunch_Values o2
  ON RIGHT(SumCustomerSaved, 1) = o2.numeric AND SIGN(SumCustomerSaved) = o2.VarCharSign

Sample results:



ID
SumCustomerPaid
SumCustomerSaved
EncodedCustomerPaid
EncodedCustomerSaved




1
0
0
00000000000{
00000000000{


2
1
-1
00000000000A
00000000000J


3
555
-555
00000000055E
00000000055N


4
123456789012
-123456789012
12345678901B
12345678901K


5
999999999999
-999999999999
99999999999I
99999999999R



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
The above assumes whole numbers. If your CustomerPaid and CustomerSaved columns have a decimal/fractional component (as is typical for currency), you will need to scale the values as appropriate, such as multiplying by 100 and then rounding/truncating to an integer.
...
-- Scaled decimal
CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,0), 100 * SUM(CustomerPaid)) AS SumCustomerPaid,
CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,0), 100 * SUM(CustomerSaved)) AS SumCustomerSaved
...

See this db<>fiddle for a scaled value implementation.
